# jGestures tap event not registering

Tags: jquery, mobile, jgestures

I'm using jQuery mobile for my mobile site. I'm trying to implement a tap on a button that I created.

I uploaded the plugin to the sever and I get no console error but for some reason its not working. Here is the code

```
    jQuery('a#nextq').bind('tapone',function(e) { alert("hi");});
```

I was using a click function at first but then I found out that sometimes click functions don't work on mobile devices. Are there any other plugins that not to complicated for a novice user?

Here is the link to the plug in http://jgestures.codeplex.com/

Comment: does this work on your desktop pc? You can click and it should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

you can either  try "on" instead of bind. Also if youre using jquery.mobile lib, you can call the "tap" event instead of tapone.